# $ f $ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(\mathrm{Int}(B))\supset \mathrm{Int}(f^{-1}(B))$

Tags: general-topology, open-map

I'm working on the following problem:

> $f$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(\mathrm{Int}(B))\supset \mathrm{Int}(f^{-1}(B))$ for all $B$.

For 
$\Longrightarrow$: Suppose $f$ is open, let $x\in \mathrm{Int}(f^{-1}(B))$, let $O$ be an open set such that $x\in O\subset f^{-1}(B)$.  Then $f(O)$ is an open set contained in $B$, hence $f(x)\in \mathrm{Int}(B)$, $x\in f^{-1}(\mathrm{Int}(B))$.

I'm stack on $\Longleftarrow$, any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O$ be an open set; you want to prove that $f(O)$ is open. Suppose otherwise. Then there is some $x\in O$ such that $f(x)\notin f(O)^\circ$. In other words, $x\notin f^{-1}\bigl(f(O)^\circ\bigr)$. But $x\in O\subset f^{-1}\bigl(f(O)\bigr)$. Since $O$ is open $x\in\bigl(f^{-1}\bigl(f(O)\bigr)\bigr)^\circ$. So, taking $B=f(O)$ this proves that $f^{-1}(B^\circ)\not\supset\bigl(f^{-1}(B)\bigr)^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prove that. Let $O$ be an open set and we want to prove that $f(O)$ is open. Take $B = f(O)$ then $f^{-1}(\text{Int}(f(O)) \supseteq \text{Int}(f^{-1}(f(O)) = \text{Int}\ O$. Note that $O = \text{Int}\ O$ because $O$ is open. So, $f^{-1}(\text{Int}(f(O)) \supseteq O$ and therefore, $\text{Int}(f(O)) \supseteq f(O)$. So, $f(O)$ is open.